# query shows data exists in the table in the sql server but it shows no row affected and return false always

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm checking if a name already exists in the database. When I execute the query in the sql server it shows data but in application, it shows, no rows affected and it always returns false.

Here is my code:

```
string productExtentionName = productExtensionEntryTextBox.Text;

bool doesProductNameExtentionExist = false;

doesProductNameExtentionExist = _aProductEntryManager.DoesProductNameAlreadyExist(productExtentionName);
         _aProduct.ProductNameExtention = productExtentionName;
        if (doesProductNameExtentionExist != true)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_aProduct.ProductNameExtention))
            {
                saveNewProduct = _aProductEntryManager.SaveProductNameExtention(_aProduct);
                if (saveNewProduct)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Product name extention saved successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error saving product name extention");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a product specication/extention");
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Product name extention / specification already exists");
        }
```

Here is my Gateway

```
public bool DoesProductNameAlreadyExist(string productExtentionName)
    {
        _connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT ProductNameExtention FROM ProductNameExtentionEntryTable WHERE ProductNameExtention='{0}'", productExtentionName);

        _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
        int affectedRows = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _connection.Close();
        if (affectedRows > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Where's your connection string? Bet a donut it has `User Instance=true` and/or `AttachDbFileName`.

Comment: A `SELECT` always returns 0 for rows affected - that value represents the number of rows that were **inserted**, **updated** or **deleted** using an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement. `SELECT` doesn't *affect* rows - it just returns them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int affectedRows = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this will return -1;

Execute the query onto a SqlDataReader and check if it has rows.
Dont forget to close the reader.

```
SqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows) MessageBox.Show("Yes"); else MessageBox.Show("No");
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
            da.SelectCommand = _command ;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
          if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                //write your code
        return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use execute scalar instead of execute non query, as this is a select query and select query does not returns the no of rows affected, which is returned by the execute non-query.

so, in this case it's returning the default value 0, hence your method is returning false.

Also, you can modify query to use top 1 1, as here you are only checking if the product exists.

SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ProductNameExtentionEntryTable WHERE ProductNameExtention=@productExtentionName